# how change properties of :before (pseudo-element) element (with jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pseudo-element

Tell me how you can change the property of the element :before?

For example:

css:

```
.myclass:before {
    content:                '';

    position:               absolute;
    left:                   40px;
    top:                    -10px;
}
```

jquery

```
myElement.addClass('myclass');
```

I want to change:

from

```
left: 40px
```

to

```
left: 100px
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pseudo-elements are not part of the DOM, so they can't be manipulated using jQuery or Javascript.

What you can try is to directly insert css using jQuery

```
$('head').append('<style>.myclass:before{left:100px;}</style>');
```

Or the way I would prefer is to add another class which has left 100 px in its CSS rule

**CSS**

```
.myclass.active:before {
    left: 100px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#myElement.myclass").addClass("active");
```

Answer (score 1):

Afaik there is no direct way to do it. If you really want to update CSS rules - then you need to go down to browser's [CSSOM interfaces](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet). But in most cases it should be easier to just define separate CSS rule that do necessary updates for your `:before` pseudo-element when assigning additional CSS class to element itself.